# CSS select when text is cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-selectors

I have a text block where the text is cut off when it doesn't fit in the block (`text-overflow: ellipsis;`). Additionally, I have a tooltip which shows the full text when hovered over the text block.

```
const CutOfContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  :hover :last-child {
    visibility: visible;
  }
`;

const CutOfText = styled.div`
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 240px;
`;

const FullTextTooltip = styled.div`
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 600px;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 999999;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
`;

const CutOfTextComponent: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <CutOfContainer>
      <CutOfText>{children}</CutOfText>
      <FullTextTooltip>{children}</FullTextTooltip>
    </CutOfContainer>
  );
};
```

Is there any way to make sure the tooltip does not pop up when the text fits in the block and is not cut off?